# what is wrong with my query?

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Match(
MId INTEGER,
TId INTEGER CONSTRAINT tid_fk REFERENCES Match(TId),
Player1 INTEGER CONSTRAINT pl1_fk REFERENCES Match(Player1),
Player2 INTEGER CONSTRAINT pl2_fk REFERENCES Match(Player2),
CHECK (Player1<>Player2),
MatchDt DATE NOT NULL,
Winner INTEGER CONSTRAINT wnnr_fk REFERENCES Match(Winner),
Score VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Id_pk PRIMARY KEY(MId,TId)
);
```

Comment: While there are some glaring errors, when you ask "what's wrong with this" you should help others help you. How? By posting the error message.  Not your description of the error. Not a transcription of the error.  Actual copy and paste of the full complete error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you want the FK constraints to do? e.g. `TId INTEGER CONSTRAINT tid_fk REFERENCES Match(TId)` What business rule do you want to enforce for column `tid`?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the "foreign key", and you can only reference primary or unique keys.

eg. [oracle tutorial](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-foreign-key/)

BTW, I've never seen a column reference itself.